# Unable to execute a if statement in exec command in python

Tags: python-3.x, exec

```
var1 = 100   
isTrue=[]
isFalse=[] 
run_cmd = f'if var1:
              print "1 - Got a true expression value"
              print var1
              isTrue.append(var1)
           else:
              print "1 - Got a false expression value"
              print var1
              isFalse.append(var1)'
exec(run_cmd)
```

**OUTPUT**

> "1 - Got a true expression value"
>    100

So above code i want to run in `exec`command , i am unable to execute in exec command in python , one liner code i am able to run ,but `if statement` as above i am unable to do so ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your string has multiple lines you need to use triple quotes like this:

```
variable = """
x = 10
print(x)
"""
```

Or single triple quotes:

```
variable = '''
x = 10
print(x)
'''
```

Also f string is unsupported in Python2 and your code can be handled without it.

Here is the code:

```
var1 = 100   
isTrue=[]
isFalse=[] 
run_cmd = '''
if var1:
    print "1 - Got a true expression value"
    print var1
    isTrue.append(var1)
else:
    print "1 - Got a false expression value"
    print var1
    isFalse.append(var1)
'''
exec(run_cmd)
```